# MPMoviePlayerController running in the background iOS

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller

Before video starts playing and touchesEnded, ViewController changes and video starts playing in a different ViewController in the background.. How can I fix this problem? What I want is, if viewController changes, then stop playing..

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];


 movpath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"video" ofType:@"m4v"];

    mpviewController = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc]
                        initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:movpath]];

    MPMoviePlayerController *mp = [mpviewController moviePlayer];
    [mp prepareToPlay];
    [mp setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];
    mp.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;

    [[mpviewController moviePlayer] play];
}

- (void) touchesEnded: (NSSet *) touches withEvent: (UIEvent *) event {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"mainView" sender:self];
    [[mpviewController moviePlayer] stop];
    [mpviewController.view removeFromSuperview];

}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13023241/continue-playing-movie-in-mpmovieplayerviewcontroller-in-background/21752593#21752593   Try this link.thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can stop your moviePlayer in -(void)viewDidDisappear method