# Play Audio in the background of my app

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, avaudioplayer

i am developing an ipad app and i want to be able to play an audio file (mp3) with the AVAudio Player, even when the App is in the background. i has this working for ios 4.2 but can't get it to work for ios 5.0 and above. please how do i achieve this in ios 5.0 and above.

thank you.

Comment: Hope this link is useful for you.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15470452/is-it-possible-to-play-video-using-avplayer-in-background

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to register your app as a background audio app by including the UIBackgroundModes key (with the value audio) in its info.plist file.

More info here : [Apple documentation Playing Background Audio](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW24)

Comment: Thanks ludoZik, this is the updated solution: All you have to do for IOS 5 and upward is register your app as a background audio by adding the property:Required background modes with value:app plays audio in your info.plist file for the application.