# Is it Possible to play video in UIwebView while app in Background mode?

Tags: ios, audio, video, background, uiwebview

In my app i have `UIWebView` in which i had give option to user for watch video from video hosting sites(i.e. Youtube, Vimeo, DailyMotion). When I click Home button the app goes to background mode, the video is paused.

I wants to Play sound of that video while app in background mode.
I had implemented same while play local video in `AVPlayer`. But till now having no luck to achieve this.
I already refereed below stuff:

--> [UIWebView: HTML5 audio pauses in iOS 6 when app enters background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11616001/uiwebview-html5-audio-pauses-in-ios-6-when-app-enters-background/12414719#12414719)

--> [Is it possible to play video using Avplayer in Background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15470452/is-it-possible-to-play-video-using-avplayer-in-background)

If you guys have any solution with this it will be great help.