# AVPlayerViewController video's audio background playing and support for multiple formats

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avplayerviewcontroller

I have to do a **Video streaming** app (using a remote url) in swift. But there is **no any exact video format**. Sometimes it can be `m3u8` sometimes `mp4` etc.. but my video player should support for what ever the format comes from the back end.

Also when the app is in background, the audio should play and when the app comes foreground video should play without any time delay between the vide and the audio.

I want to know whether is it possible to achieve my objectives using `AVPlayerViewController` or else what is the best player that I can use to achieve my targets. Please help me.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

AVPlayerViewController supports m3u8 and mp4 both format. For playing video's audio you need some extra configuration. You can check from here...

[How do I get my AVPlayer to play while app is in background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4771105/how-do-i-get-my-avplayer-to-play-while-app-is-in-background)

[Is it possible to play video using Avplayer in Background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15470452/is-it-possible-to-play-video-using-avplayer-in-background)

So according to me AVPlayerViewController is best option for your requirement.